# PHP for loop : equal or smaller than - works, equal to - creates infinte loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

This code works

```
<?php 
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
        echo "The number is: $x <br>";
    } 
?>
```

but if instead of " <= " I use simply " = " php gets into an infinite loop that timesout

```
<?php 
        for ($x = 0; $x = 10; $x++) {
            echo "The number is: $x <br>";
        } 
?>
```

Is that expected behavior?

Comment: You don't use `=` to compare but `==` or `===`. But in that case your loop would not run at all, so what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're using an *assignment* operator instead of a *comparison* operator. Now there's no way for that loop to end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's expected.

You must use <= instead of = only

<= is a comparaison operator : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

= is an assignment operator : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: what about `==`, which is what OP should really be using if they want to see if the value is equal. Even though I know it will not loop at all because the middle part of the for loop will never be true.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback - Im currently learning php and was partially aware of the comparison/assignment thing but why does it not run at all with == ? $x is never defined before and is defined as 0 to start with here so why does it never equal 10?

Comment: Just got it - with == it runs only if x is 10 which is not the case - coming from VBA where the for loop's logic would be FOR x = 0 TO 10 - it confused me. Thanks again